# Django static file 404 errors when deployed with mod_wsgi

Tags: css, django, mod-wsgi

I am getting 404 errors on all of my static files when I try to deploy them in production

[A live page of the site is available here](http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/slide_test/). Inspecting the page in Chromes Console or Firebug will show the below issues.

[image]

I cant understand why this is happening as the above 404 errors match perfectly to the locations of my CSS files
`/var/www/bias_experiment/static/survey/css/bootstrap.css`

I've tried to solve this for a few days but cant crack the problem.

Below is all of my setup. I thought it best to include everything that might be useful and all the steps I have taken. Apologies for the length.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/bias_experiment/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/bias_experiment/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
                    '/var/www/bias_experiment/src/survey/static/survey/css', 
                    '/var/www/bias_experiment/src/survey/static/survey/js', 
                    '/var/www/bias_experiment/src/survey/static/survey/fonts', 
)
```

I am using `STATIC_URL = '/bias_experiment/static/'` because I am using a VM which has been made publicly available through http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/

If I use `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` I get 403 forbidden errors.

**slide_test.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}      
<!-- THESE WORK LOCALY BUT DO NOT WORK ON THE SERVER -->              
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="{% static "survey/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" >
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="{% static "survey/css/bootstrap.css" %}">               
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="{% static "survey/css/jquery-ui.css" %}">                 
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="{% static "survey/css/slider.css" %}">                

<script src="{% static "survey/js/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>               
<script src="{% static "survey/js/jquery-ui.js" %}"></script>   
<script src="{% static "survey/js/slider.js" %}"></script>
```

**My default apache file** /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/static/
<Directory /var/www/bias_experiment/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment>
<Files index.wsgi>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

...
standard apache default settings here
...

</VirtualHost>
```

As per the DjangoProject 1.6 Documentation (I am using Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu))

> If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace Require
>   all granted with Allow from all and also add the line Order deny,allow
>   above it.

I have restarted and reloaded Apache

`sudo service apache2 restart` `sudo service apache2 reload`

I have no problem running collectstatic

[image]

I have set ownership of the collected files to www-data:www-data with the below command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/bias_experiment/static/
```

[image]

I have even disabled and re-enabled the default file in apache2

```
sudo a2dissite default

sudo a2ensite default
```

and then restarted

`sudo service apache2 restart` `sudo service apache2 reload`

I am using

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache 2.22
- Django 1.6
- mod_wsgi Version: 3.3-4ubuntu0.1

An absolute path to one of the CSS files is http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/static/survey/css/bootstrap.min in case it is of any use.

However I cant seem to get the [test deployment page I am working to show its CSS or JS](http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/slide_test/). 
I really am not sure what I'm leaving out. If anyone can make any suggestions it would be hugely appreciated.

I asked a similar question to this a few days ago which i have deleted as there were too many mistakes on my part and it lacked both detail and a clear issue.

Thanks

Comment: As what user is the Apache process running? Does this user have read/execute permissions on the static folder and it's contents? I believe either the alias in your config should be `Alias /bias_experiment/static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/static/` or your `STATIC_URL` should be `/static/`, or these two will mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

```
STATIC_URL = '/bias_experiment/static/'
```

in the Django settings module, you should be using:

```
Alias /bias_experiment/static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/static/
```

in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `STATIC_ROOT` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. They shouldn't be the same. Because when you run `python manage.py collectstatic` for deployment they will be overwritten and also take a look at this page [Managing static files (CSS, images)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)
    #settings.py
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    # STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

```
# Introduce templates
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'somewhereelse'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
)
```

And this code for WSGI works for me

```
import os
import sys
import pprint
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Yourapp.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
class LoggingMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.__application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
        pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', environ), stream=errors)

        def _start_response(status, headers, *args):
            pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errors)
            return start_response(status, headers, *args)

        return self.__application(environ, _start_response)

application = LoggingMiddleware(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

path = '/var/www/example.com'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```